# Google Cloud Function throwing a 404 error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I created a Cloud Function which is set to be triggered by a Finalize/Create event on a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

I dumped 10k images into the bucket, and the majority of the images ran the Cloud Function successfully, while some threw the following exception and I'm just confused on what is causing this error.

The error is returning a 404, but when I check the bucket, the image is there. Does anyone have experience with fixing the following exception?

For some reason the Cloud Function is checking a directory that does not exist.

It should check the following directory:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/hidden-name/images%2F3683740a95fa3600d4d9a220c9e0b472.jpg
```

However, it is checking the following directory instead, which does not exist (`/o` folder does not exist):

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/hidden-name/o/images%2F3683740a95fa3600d4d9a220c9e0b472.jpg
```

This is the exception I'm getting:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py",
>   line 721, in download_to_file transport, file_obj, download_url,
>   headers, start, end, raw_download File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py",
>   line 645, in _do_download download.consume(transport) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/download.py",
>   line 153, in consume self._process_response(result) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/_download.py",
>   line 171, in _process_response response, _ACCEPTABLE_STATUS_CODES,
>   self._get_status_code File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/_helpers.py",
>   line 96, in require_status_code *status_codes
>   google.resumable_media.common.InvalidResponse: ('Request failed with
>   status code', 404, 'Expected one of', ,
>   ) During handling of the above
>   exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call
>   last): File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py",
>   line 383, in run_background_function
>   _function_handler.invoke_user_function(event_object) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py",
>   line 217, in invoke_user_function return
>   call_user_function(request_or_event) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py",
>   line 214, in call_user_function
>   event_context.Context(**request_or_event.context)) File
>   "/user_code/main.py", line 44, in for_each_new_image
>   create_thumb_move_to_thumbs_bucket(bucket_name,blob_name) File
>   "/user_code/main.py", line 56, in create_thumb_move_to_thumbs_bucket
>   blob_in_bucket.download_to_filename(download_tmp_filepath) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py",
>   line 761, in download_to_filename raw_download=raw_download, File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py",
>   line 724, in download_to_file _raise_from_invalid_response(exc) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py",
>   line 2161, in _raise_from_invalid_response raise
>   exceptions.from_http_status(response.status_code, message,
>   response=response) google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 GET
>   https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/hidden-name/o/images%2F3683740a95fa3600d4d9a220c9e0b472.jpg?alt=media:
>   ('Request failed with status code', 404, 'Expected one of',
>   , )

Cloud function entry method:

```
def for_each_new_image(event, context):   
    blob_name = event['name'].lower()
    bucket_name = event['bucket']   
    create_thumb_move_to_thumbs_bucket(bucket_name,blob_name)
```

Method which throws the error:

```
def create_thumb_move_to_thumbs_bucket(bucket_name,blob_name):     
    bucket = _storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob_in_bucket = bucket.blob(blob_name)

    blob_name = blob_name.replace("ugc_images/","")    
    thumbnail_filename = blob_name.replace(".","-sm.")

    thumbnail_tmp_filepath = '/tmp/{}'.format(thumbnail_filename)       
    download_tmp_filepath = '/tmp/{}'.format(blob_name)    

    blob_in_bucket.download_to_filename(download_tmp_filepath)
```

Line which throws the error:

```
blob_in_bucket.download_to_filename(download_tmp_filepath)
```

Comment: Have you uploaded the same file twice ?
The Object Finalize will trigger even though it is overwritten.

If I click on second URL, it says
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Only media downloads requests can be sent to /download/*. Re-send request to the same path, but without the /download prefix.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Only media downloads requests can be sent to /download/*. Re-send request to the same path, but without the /download prefix.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notDownload"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: @VikramShinde Nope, all unique images. Also i  made the URLs dummy, meaning they aren't live

Comment: can you please share your code with us?

Comment: @Chris32 Instead of adding all of the lines of code, i added the method/line where the exception is thrown: "blob_in_bucket.download_to_filename(download_tmp_filepath)"

Comment: Could you add enough code to make it reproducible. This will also give us more context to be able to help

Comment: @JoséSoní i added the cloud function entry method "for_each_new_image" which calls method "create_thumb_move_to_thumbs_bucket". To reproduce you need to setup a bucket in GCP and dump 10K+ images there with the cloud function subscribed to a finalize/create event. Each image is downloaded with "download_to_filename" method

Comment: are you doing something with the images once in '/tmp/{}'.format(blob_name)    location?

Comment: @JoséSoní yes i'm downloading them and converting images to thumbs with a size of 120x120. But the code doesn't get to that step, it fails on "download_to_filename" method call.

Comment: what is the error proportion? does your GCF has the retry on failure enabled?

Comment: @JoséSoní the retry is NOT enabled in GCF

Comment: if the errors are in a small proportion then you can try enabling the retry on GCF. Can you say what is the proportion of the error?

Comment: @JoséSoní I did have retry ENABLED, and all that does is just repeat this error forever. I had to turn off retry on GCF. The proportion of this error is about 5-10%

Comment: are you logging the destination path before actually using it, this can help to see if the error is when creating the destination path or in the usage of it

Comment: @JoséSoní the error occurs when the file is downloaded with 'download_to_filename' method call which is taking place way before the file is thumbed and moved to another destination. All of the images are sharing the same destination. The GCF works for 95% of the images.

Comment: could you try logging the destination of each file before the download is made? this is to verify if the issue is happening when generating the destination file or on the step of the download. I tried to do it in my side but was not able to replicate the issue

Comment: @JoséSoní the stack trace confirms that this error happens on download "line 761, in download_to_filename raw_download=raw_download, File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 724, in download_to_file _raise_from_invalid_response(exc) " Logging of the destination will never get hit, since the error happens before the thumb is moved

Comment: yes but in the stacktrace is at the moment of the error, and The log I am asking you is before. This is to be able to know if the error is caused on the transfer method or before. As if it is caused before with a simple replace you can catch the faulty path and solve it