# What is https://storage.googleapis.com and how do I use and explore it?

Tags: tensorflow

I've been seeing such snippets in a lot of notebooks of tensorflow tutorials

```
!wget --no-check-certificate \
    https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5 \
    -O /tmp/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5
```

I understand we're downloading a pretrained model here and in other cases we can download datasets
Now I want to explore what else I can download, for example I wanted to download caltech256 dataset like this, but I don't know if that is even an option because if you go to googleapis.com, you get error 404, besides I cant find any resources explaining what it is and how to use it .

So how do I explore it, all the efforts are appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are facing 404 error, it means those files has  got restricted access or files has been removed by author from google cloud. To explore various public Datasets /pre-trained solutions .

Visit

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/datasets

Reference
[Google Cloud Function throwing a 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736393/google-cloud-function-throwing-a-404-error)